# how to use the javascript function getTotal to be used more than one function in one html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have 23 range sliders with a range of  0 to 10. I want to be able to add up the value range sliders. for example AVERAGE WELLBEING = (slider 1 + 2 +3 +4 ....+22+23)/23):

```
function getTotal() {
  var e1 = parseInt(slider2.value) || 0;
  var e2 = parseInt(slider10.value) || 0;
  var e3 = parseInt(slider16.value) || 0;
  var h1 = parseInt(slider6.value) || 0;
  var h2 = parseInt(slider11.value) || 0;
  var h3 = parseInt(slider17.value) || 0;
  var a1 = parseInt(slider.value) || 0;
  var a2 = parseInt(slider5.value) || 0;
  var a3 = parseInt(slider14.value) || 0;
  var m1 = parseInt(slider7.value) || 0;
  var m2 = parseInt(slider9.value) || 0;
  var m3 = parseInt(slider19.value) || 0;
  var hap = parseInt(slider23.value) || 0;
  var r1= parseInt(slider8.value) || 0;
  var r2 = parseInt(slider18.value) || 0;
  var r3 = parseInt(slider20.value) || 0;
  var p1 = parseInt(slider4.value) || 0;
  var p2 = parseInt(slider12.value) || 0;
  var p3 = parseInt(slider22.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 +h1+h2+h3+r1+r2+r3+a1+a2+a3+hap+m1+m2+m3+p1+p2+p3 )/23;
```

POSITIVE EMOTION = (slider 2+9+11)/3

```
function getTotal() {
  var p1 = parseInt(slider4.value) || 0;
  var p2 = parseInt(slider12.value) || 0;
  var p3 = parseInt(slider22.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalPE").innerHTML = (p1 + p2+ p3 )/3;
```

so i have figured out how to do that using the getTotal function in js but what im not able to do is have positive emotion and average wellbeing and others to calculate at the same time.
here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inkel.ie</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/java.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script>
  $(function(){
    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
      var file =  $(this).data('include') + '.html';
      $(this).load(file);
    });
  });
</script>
    <div data-include="About"></div>
<div data-include="Contact"></div>
    <div data-include="Projects"></div>
<div data-include="Projects2"></div>

</head>
<body>

    <header id="header1">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="logo">
            <p>Inkel.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="underlogo">
        <p>The science of positive Psycology</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Daily Tracker</a></li>


        </ul>
        </div>

    </header>

    <div class="container"><div id="number">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider"></div>
    <p id="a1" >Moving towards work goals</p>
        <div class="container2"><div id="number2">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider2"></div>
    <p id="e1" >In the zone at work</p>
        <div class="container3"><div id="number3">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider3"></div>
    <p id="n1" >Any anxiety at work</p>
        <div class="container4"><div id="number4">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider4"></div>
    <p id="p1" >Feeling great at work</p>
      <div class="container5"><div id="number5">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider5"></div>
    <p id="a2"> You achieving work goals</p>
        <div class="container6"><div id="number6">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider6"></div>
    <p id="h1">How's your physical health. </p>
        <div class="container7"><div id="number7">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider7"></div>
     <p id="m1">Work giving you purpose?</p>
        <div class="container8"><div id="number8">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider8"></div>
    <p id="r1">Others support you in work? </p>
    <div class="container9"><div id="number9">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider9"></div>
    <p id="m2">Is your work worthwhile? </p>
        <div class="container10"><div id="number10">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider10"></div>
    <p id="e2"> Is your work exciting?</p>
        <div class="container11"><div id="number11">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider11"></div>
     <p id="h2">Satisfied with physical health</p>
    <div class="container12"><div id="number12">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider12"></div>
    <p id="p2">Positive often</p>
    <div class="container13"><div id="number13">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider13"></div>
        <p id="n2">Work making you angry</p>
    <div class="container14"><div id="number14">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider14"></div>
    <p id="a3">Handling work duties.</p>
        <div class="container15"><div id="number15">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider15"></div>
    <p id="n3">Sad in work?</p>
        <div class="container16"><div id="number16">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider16"></div>
    <p id="e3">Work you enjoy at work.</p>
        <div class="container17"><div id="number17">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider17"></div>
    <p id="h3">Your health V others ?</p>
    <div class="container18"><div id="number18">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider18"></div>
    <p id="r2">appriciated at work</p>
        <div class="container19"><div id="number19">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider19"></div>
    <p id="m3">Work giving life direction</p>
        <div class="container20"><div id="number20">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider20"></div>
    <p id="r3">Happy with prof. rel..ps</p>
    <div class="container22"><div id="number22">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider22"></div>
    <p id="p3">Life good in work?</p>
    <div class="container23"><div id="number23">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider23"></div>
    <p id="hap">How happy are you?</p>

    <p id="mon">Monday</p>
    <p id="tue">Tuesday</p>
    <p id="wed">Wednesday</p>
    <p id="thu">Thursday</p>
    <p id="fri">Friday</p>


    <div id="totals">
      <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">WB
          <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Average WellBeing:<span id="total"></span></span>
        </div>

        <p> Positive Emotion :<span id="totalPE"></span></p>


      <p>Engagement :<span id="totalE"></span></p>

      <p>Relationships :<span id="totalR"></span></p>

      <p>Meaning :<span id="totalM"></span></p>

      <p>Accomplishments :<span id="totalA"></span></p>

      <p>Health :<span id="totalH"></span></p>
    </div>

   <script>
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
    <script>
        var slider=document.
            getElementById("slider");
        var number=document.
            getElementById("number");
        slider.oninput=function(){
            number.innerHTML=slider.
                value;}
    </script>
    <script>
         var slider2=document.
            getElementById("slider2");
        var number2=document.
            getElementById("number2");
        slider2.oninput=function(){
            number2.innerHTML=slider2.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider3=document.
            getElementById("slider3");
        var number3=document.
            getElementById("number3");
        slider3.oninput=function(){
            number3.innerHTML=slider3.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider4=document.
            getElementById("slider4");
        var number4=document.
            getElementById("number4");
        slider4.oninput=function(){
            number4.innerHTML=slider4.
                value;}



slider4.oninput = function() {

  number4.innerHTML = this.value;
}
$(function() {
  $('input[type=range]').change(getTotal); // not () - you're not calling the function
  getTotal(); // initialy call it
});







function getTotal() {
  var e1 = parseInt(slider2.value) || 0;
  var e2 = parseInt(slider10.value) || 0;
  var e3 = parseInt(slider16.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalE").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 )/3;

}


function getTotal() {
  var p1 = parseInt(slider4.value) || 0;
  var p2 = parseInt(slider12.value) || 0;
  var p3 = parseInt(slider22.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalPE").innerHTML = (p1 + p2+ p3 )/3;

}

function getTotal() {
  var r1= parseInt(slider8.value) || 0;
  var r2 = parseInt(slider18.value) || 0;
  var r3 = parseInt(slider20.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalR").innerHTML = (r1 + r2+ r3 )/3;

}

function getTotal() {
  var m1 = parseInt(slider7.value) || 0;
  var m2 = parseInt(slider9.value) || 0;
  var m3 = parseInt(slider19.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalM").innerHTML = (m1 + m2+ m3 )/3;

}

function getTotal() {
  var a1 = parseInt(slider.value) || 0;
  var a2 = parseInt(slider5.value) || 0;
  var a3 = parseInt(slider14.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalA").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 )/3;

}

function getTotal() {
  var h1 = parseInt(slider6.value) || 0;
  var h2 = parseInt(slider11.value) || 0;
  var h3 = parseInt(slider17.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalH").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 )/3;

}

function getTotal() {
    var e1 = parseInt(slider2.value) || 0;
  var e2 = parseInt(slider10.value) || 0;
  var e3 = parseInt(slider16.value) || 0;
     var h1 = parseInt(slider6.value) || 0;
  var h2 = parseInt(slider11.value) || 0;
  var h3 = parseInt(slider17.value) || 0;
    var a1 = parseInt(slider.value) || 0;
  var a2 = parseInt(slider5.value) || 0;
  var a3 = parseInt(slider14.value) || 0;
     var m1 = parseInt(slider7.value) || 0;
  var m2 = parseInt(slider9.value) || 0;
  var m3 = parseInt(slider19.value) || 0;
      var hap = parseInt(slider23.value) || 0;
      var r1= parseInt(slider8.value) || 0;
  var r2 = parseInt(slider18.value) || 0;
  var r3 = parseInt(slider20.value) || 0;
      var p1 = parseInt(slider4.value) || 0;
  var p2 = parseInt(slider12.value) || 0;
  var p3 = parseInt(slider22.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 +h1+h2+h3+r1+r2+r3+a1+a2+a3+hap+m1+m2+m3+p1+p2+p3 )/23;

}




    </script>

     <script>
        var slider5=document.
            getElementById("slider5");
        var number5=document.
            getElementById("number5");
        slider5.oninput=function(){
            number5.innerHTML=slider5.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
         var slider6=document.
            getElementById("slider6");
        var number6=document.
            getElementById("number6");
        slider6.oninput=function(){
            number6.innerHTML=slider6.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider7=document.
            getElementById("slider7");
        var number7=document.
            getElementById("number7");
        slider7.oninput=function(){
            number7.innerHTML=slider7.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider8=document.
            getElementById("slider8");
        var number8=document.
            getElementById("number8");
        slider8.oninput=function(){
            number8.innerHTML=slider8.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider9=document.
            getElementById("slider9");
        var number9=document.
            getElementById("number9");
        slider9.oninput=function(){
            number9.innerHTML=slider9.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
         var slider10=document.
            getElementById("slider10");
        var number10=document.
            getElementById("number10");
        slider10.oninput=function(){
            number10.innerHTML=slider10.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider11=document.
            getElementById("slider11");
        var number11=document.
            getElementById("number11");
        slider11.oninput=function(){
            number11.innerHTML=slider11.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider12=document.
            getElementById("slider12");
        var number12=document.
            getElementById("number12");
        slider12.oninput=function(){
            number12.innerHTML=slider12.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider13=document.
            getElementById("slider13");
        var number13=document.
            getElementById("number13");
        slider13.oninput=function(){
            number13.innerHTML=slider13.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider14=document.
            getElementById("slider14");
        var number14=document.
            getElementById("number14");
        slider14.oninput=function(){
            number14.innerHTML=slider14.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
         var slider15=document.
            getElementById("slider15");
        var number15=document.
            getElementById("number15");
        slider15.oninput=function(){
            number15.innerHTML=slider15.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider16=document.
            getElementById("slider16");
        var number16=document.
            getElementById("number16");
        slider16.oninput=function(){
            number16.innerHTML=slider16.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider17=document.
            getElementById("slider17");
        var number4=document.
            getElementById("number17");
        slider17.oninput=function(){
            number17.innerHTML=slider17.
                value;}
        </script>

    <script>
        var slider18=document.
            getElementById("slider18");
        var number18=document.
            getElementById("number18");
        slide18.oninput=function(){
            number18.innerHTML=slider18.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
         var slider19=document.
            getElementById("slider19");
        var number19=document.
            getElementById("number19");
        slider19.oninput=function(){
            number19.innerHTML=slider19.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider20=document.
            getElementById("slider20");
        var number20=document.
            getElementById("number20");
        slider20.oninput=function(){
            number20.innerHTML=slider20.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider21=document.
            getElementById("slider21");
        var number21=document.
            getElementById("number21");
        slider21.oninput=function(){
            number21.innerHTML=slider21.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider22=document.
            getElementById("slider22");
        var number22=document.
            getElementById("number22");
        slider22.oninput=function(){
            number22.innerHTML=slider22.
                value;}
        </script>
    <script>
        var slider23=document.
            getElementById("slider23");
        var number23=document.
            getElementById("number23");
        slider23.oninput=function(){
            number23.innerHTML=slider23.
                value;}
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a link to css 
https://inkeltracker.000webhostapp.com/css/style2.css

Comment: There's a comment in the code saying you aren't calling your `getTotal()` function in the `.change()`.

If that isn't the problem, please provide more information about what's happening when you change a value. 

It's also typically helpful to use the developer tools of the browser you're testing in, as sometimes you'll get helpful messages in the console.

Comment: hey stephan here is a link to the tracker , move all the slides and click on wb to view the value...inkeltracker.000webhostapp.com .... i thought with the code abouve i could see wellbeing beinng calculated aswel as positive emotions and the rest at the same time. im not sure what u mean but can u take a look

Comment: somewhat unrelated, but you should consider rewriting your JS code using arrays to greatly simplify and shorten it.

Comment: You have the same function `getTotal()` defined at least 7 times...

Comment: Why are you closing and opening all the script tags when there's nothing between them? Just include all the JS in one <script> tag.

Comment: Only the last getTotal() function will be called, as each time you define a getTotal() function you're overwriting the last one.

Comment: @Ivan86 thanks so much that was where i was going wrong i deleted all the get totals and just had one then i put the sum under one get total and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can add common classes to the elements that you want to be calculated together, which would greatly simplify your code like below:

**Note:** Only 3 elements are part of this example, just to show the logic. I wrapped everything in `on DOM ready` so we are sure that the elements exist on the page before we try to query for them. Pay attention to the classes of the range elements.

---

**Example:** (run it below)

```js
// on DOM ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  // finds all elements with class "emotion" and stores them in a variable
  var emotions = document.querySelectorAll(".emotion");
  var wellbeing = document.querySelectorAll(".wellbeing");

  // send the array and a reference of the function we want called when the event happens
  prepareListeners(emotions, getEmotionTotal);
  prepareListeners(wellbeing, getWellbeingTotal);

  // add "onchange" listeners to elements of an array
  function prepareListeners(array, callback) {
    array.forEach(function(item) {
      item.addEventListener("change", callback);
    });
  }

  // function to calculate sum
  function calcSum(array) {
    let val, sum = 0;
  
    array.forEach(function(item) {
      val = parseInt(item.value);
      sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
    });
    
    return sum;
  }

  // Emotional function
  function getEmotionTotal() {
    let sum;
    // here we could have just written return calcSum(emotions); but I 
    // intentionally wrote it like this so we can see the console.log()
    sum = calcSum(emotions);
    
    console.log("Emotional is: " + sum); // just to print it out here
    return sum; // you can return the sum to the caller or put it in a div somewhere
  }

  // Wellbeing function
  function getWellbeingTotal() {
    let sum;
    sum = calcSum(wellbeing);
    
    console.log("Wellbeing is: " + sum);
    return sum;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="number">0</div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10" class="emotion" value="0" id="slider">
</div>
<p id="a1">Moving towards work goals</p>
<div class="container2">
  <div id="number2">0</div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10" class="emotion wellbeing" value="0" id="slider2">
</div>
<p id="e1">In the zone at work</p>
<div class="container3">
  <div id="number3">0</div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10" class="emotion wellbeing" value="0" id="slider3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTotal() {
  var e1 = parseInt(slider2.value) || 0;
  var e2 = parseInt(slider10.value) || 0;
  var e3 = parseInt(slider16.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalE").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 )/3;   
  var p1 = parseInt(slider4.value) || 0;
  var p2 = parseInt(slider12.value) || 0;
  var p3 = parseInt(slider22.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalPE").innerHTML = (p1 + p2+ p3 )/3;
  var r1= parseInt(slider8.value) || 0;
  var r2 = parseInt(slider18.value) || 0;
  var r3 = parseInt(slider20.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalR").innerHTML = (r1 + r2+ r3 )/3;
  var m1 = parseInt(slider7.value) || 0;
  var m2 = parseInt(slider9.value) || 0;
  var m3 = parseInt(slider19.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalM").innerHTML = (m1 + m2+ m3 )/3;

  var a1 = parseInt(slider.value) || 0;
  var a2 = parseInt(slider5.value) || 0;
  var a3 = parseInt(slider14.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalA").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 )/3;
  var h1 = parseInt(slider6.value) || 0;
  var h2 = parseInt(slider11.value) || 0;
  var h3 = parseInt(slider17.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("totalH").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 )/3;

      var hap = parseInt(slider23.value) || 0;

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = (e1 + e2+ e3 +h1+h2+h3+r1+r2+r3+a1+a2+a3+hap+m1+m2+m3+p1+p2+p3 )/23;

}
```

thanks to @Ivan86

Comment: If my answer answered your question consider matking it as accepted. Thanks